# Access nested nodes in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have the following sudo html

```
<foo>
    <span>Bar</span>
</foo>
```

and directive:

```
myapp.directive('foo', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div><p>{{usedToBeInSpan}}</p></div>'
    }
});
```

How can I extract the contents of the nested `span` node and set its contents in the directives scope to `usedToBeInSpan`?

*Note that I am not actually using this to replace a nested tag, it's just a simplified example*

Comment: you have to create `link` function and extract all html content from `span` using `.html()` and add in your template

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava Thanks, see my question on @manasisakhare's answer... what do I use the `.html()` function on?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a link function in your directive as below:

```
myapp.directive('foo', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div><p>{{usedToBeInSpan}}</p></div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           // the element argument contains the html content inside the directive tags <foo></foo>
          scope.usedToBeInSpan = "";//populate from "element"
    }
}
});
```

Comment: That's exactly as far as I understand it. How do I access / populate the nested elements inside my directive?

Comment: you can use the traditional HTML Element methods which you can find under: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp or http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp

Comment: in the link function, check the second argument it is an html "Element"

Comment: Right, but what that gives me is the html of the template, not the html of the nested nodes of my directive tag.

Answer (score 0):

Found a new solution. Angular creates a css class named after the directive content, like "ng-<directive>-content" using this you can access the content of the directive where it was used. Have a look at this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/manasisakhare/8ezh35to/2/

```
myapp.directive('foo', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div><p class="ng-foo-content" ng-transclude></p></div>'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems interesting. When I run the fiddle, the ´<foo>´ tag still wraps the correctly replaced content.